# STL vector corrupted for no reason, VC++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap-corruption

I'm making a program for searching T-spin elevator.
https://youtu.be/F3rhyJqusE4

But I have a problem with dealing `spin_env` variable, which is defined like this:

```
struct spin_environment {
    vector< pair<int, int> > AND;
    vector< vector <pair<int, int> > > OR;
};
spin_environment spin_env[4][2][5];
```

Especially `spin_env[1][1][2].AND` is corrupted during backtracking. When I initialized it, its size was **1**. But during backtracking, suddenly the size of it bumped to **536870911**, and all address of content in it can't have been found. But any other contents in `spin_env`, like `spin_env[3][0][1].AND`, didn't change.

So I thought this should be a memory problem, so I set reserved memory amount to 1GB at heap, 200MB at stack(default of this are both 1MB). But same problem has occurred and even when I took a memory snapshot, there was no change at how many memory I use.

I wonder why this error happened and how to fix it. Please help! The IDE I use is Visual Studio C++ 2017, building in x86 debug mode.

The whole code is described below (sorry for little comment)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<pair<int, int>> offset[4][2] = {
    { { { -1, 0 },{ -1, 1 } },{ { 1, 0 },{ 1, 1 } } },
    { { { 1, 0 },{ 0, 2 },{ 0, 2 },{ 1, 2 },{ 1,2 } },{ { 1, 0 },{ 0, 2 },{ 1, 2 } } },
    { { { 1, 0 } },{ { -1, 0 } } },
    { { { -1, 0 },{ 0, 2 },{ -1,2 } },{ { -1, 0 },{ 0, 2 },{ 0, 2 },{ -1,2 },{ -1,2 } } }
};
pair<int, int> block[4][4] = {
    { { 0, 0 },{ 1, 0 },{ -1, 0 },{ 0, 1 } },
    { { 0, 0 },{ 1, 0 },{ 0, -1 },{ 0, 1 } },
    { { 0, 0 },{ 1, 0 },{ -1, 0 },{ 0, -1 } },
    { { 0, 0 },{ 0, -1 },{ -1, 0 },{ 0, 1 } }
};
struct spin_environment {
    vector< pair<int, int> > AND;
    vector< vector <pair<int, int> > > OR;
};
spin_environment spin_env[4][2][5];
vector<int> state_order = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 0}, spin_order = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
vector<vector<int>> answer;

int field[10][20];
pair<int, int> center = { 5, 18 };
void simulation(int);

pair<int, int> operator+ (pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {
    return { a.first + b.first, a.second + b.second };
}

//initialize spin_env
void initialization() {
    spin_env[0][0][0].AND = { { 0, -1 } };
    spin_env[0][0][1].AND = { { 0, -1 },{ -1, -1 } };
    spin_env[0][1][0].AND = { { 0, -1 } };
    spin_env[0][1][1].AND = { { 0, -1 },{ 1, -1 } };

    spin_env[1][0][0].AND = { { -1, 0 } };

    spin_env[1][0][1].AND = { { -1, 0 },{ 1, -1 } };
    spin_env[1][0][2].AND = { { -1, 0 },{ 2,0 } };
    spin_env[1][0][2].OR = { { { 1, -1 },{ 2, -1 },{ 1, -2 } } };

    spin_env[1][0][3].AND = { { -1, 0 },{ 1, -1 },{ -1, 2 } };
    spin_env[1][0][4].AND = { { -1, 0 },{ 2,0 },{ -1, 2 } };
    spin_env[1][0][4].OR = { { { 1, -1 },{ 2, -1 },{ 1, -2 } } };

    spin_env[1][1][0].AND = { { -1, 0 } };

    spin_env[1][1][1].AND = { { -1, 0 } };
    spin_env[1][1][1].OR = { { { 1, -1 },{ 2, -1 } },{ { 2, 0 },{ 1, 1 } } };

    spin_env[1][1][2].AND = { { -1, 0 } };
    spin_env[1][1][2].OR = { { { 1, -1 },{ 2, -1 } },{ { 2, 0 },{ 1, 1 } },{ { -1, 2 },{ 0, 3 } } };

    spin_env[2][0][0].AND = { { 0, 1 } };

    spin_env[2][1][0].AND = { { 0, 1 } };

    spin_env[3][0][0].AND = { { 1, 0 } };

    spin_env[3][0][1].AND = { { 1, 0 } };
    spin_env[3][0][1].OR = { { { -1, -1 },{ -2, -1 } },{ { -2, 0 },{ -1, 1 } } };

    spin_env[3][0][2].AND = { { 1, 0 } };
    spin_env[3][0][2].OR = { { { -1, -1 },{ -2, -1 } },{ { -2, 0 },{ -1, 1 } },{ { 1, 2 },{ 0, 3 } } };

    spin_env[3][1][0].AND = { { 1, 0 } };

    spin_env[3][1][1].AND = { { 1, 0 },{ -1, -1 } };
    spin_env[3][1][2].AND = { { 1, 0 },{ -2,0 } };
    spin_env[3][1][2].OR = { { { -1, -1 },{ -2, -1 },{ -1, -2 } } };

    spin_env[3][1][3].AND = { { 1, 0 },{ -1, -1 },{ 1, 2 } };
    spin_env[3][1][4].AND = { { 1, 0 },{ -2,0 },{ 1, 2 } };
    spin_env[3][1][4].OR = { { { -1, -1 },{ -2, -1 },{ -1, -2 } } };
}

//subroutine function of simulation()
void subroutine(int index, int s, int c, int t, int sub_index) {
    if (sub_index == spin_env[s][c][t].OR.size()) {
        center.first += offset[s][c][t].first;
        center.second -= offset[s][c][t].second;
        simulation(index + 1);
        center.first -= offset[s][c][t].first;
        center.second += offset[s][c][t].second;
        return;
    }
    int pass = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < spin_env[s][c][t].OR[sub_index].size(); i++) {
        pair<int, int> temp = spin_env[s][c][t].OR[sub_index][i];
        if (field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] == 1) 
{
            pass = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (pass) {
        subroutine(index, s, c, t, sub_index + 1);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < spin_env[s][c][t].OR[sub_index].size(); i++) {
        pair<int, int> temp = spin_env[s][c][t].OR[sub_index][i];
        if (field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] == -1) 
continue;
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 1;
        subroutine(index, s, c, t, sub_index + 1);
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 0;
    }
}

//recursive function for backtracking
void simulation(int index) {

    if (index == spin_order.size()) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                switch (field[y][x]) {
                case 1:
                    printf("1 ");
                    break;
                case -1:
                    printf("X ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("  ");
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return;
    }

    int s, c, t;
    pair<int, int> temp;
    s = state_order[index];
    t = spin_order[index];

    switch (state_order[index + 1] - s) {
    case 1:
    case -3:
        c = 0;
        break;
    case -1:
    case 3:
        c = 1;
        break;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < spin_env[s][c][t].AND.size(); j++) {
        temp = spin_env[s][c][t].AND[j];
        if (field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] == -1) 
{
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        temp = block[state_order[index + 1]][j] + offset[s][c][t];
        if (field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] == 1) 
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < spin_env[s][c][t].AND.size(); j++) {
        temp = spin_env[s][c][t].AND[j];
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        temp = block[state_order[index + 1]][j] + offset[s][c][t];
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = -1;
    }
    subroutine(index, s, c, t, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < spin_env[s][c][t].AND.size(); j++) {
        temp = spin_env[s][c][t].AND[j];
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        temp = block[state_order[index + 1]][j] + offset[s][c][t];
        field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 0;
    }
}

//recursive fuction for generate permutation
void permutation(int index) {
    if (index == spin_order.size()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pair<int, int> temp = block[state_order[0]][j];
            field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = -1;
        }
        simulation(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pair<int, int> temp = block[state_order[0]][j];
            field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = 0;
        }
        return;
    }

    int k;

    switch (state_order[index]) {
    case 0:
        k = 2;
        break;
    case 1:
        if (state_order[index + 1] == 2) k = 5;
        else k = 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        k = 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        if (state_order[index + 1] == 2) k = 5;
        else k = 3;
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        spin_order[index] = i;
        permutation(index + 1);
    }
}
int main() {
    initialization();
    permutation(0);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array` throughout your program, and do not use raw arrays.  Change `int field[10][20];` to `std::vector<std::vector<int>> field(10, std::vector<int>(20));`.  Since you're using Visual Studio, you will then see the error in debug mode (you are going out-of-bounds).  Using raw arrays, you get little to no chance to detect boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your code as-is, and simply changing the declaration of `field` to this detects you are going out of bounds in `field`:

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> field(10, std::vector<int>(20));`

Since you are using Visual Studio and you are running in debug mode, Visual C++ in debug mode detects out-of-bounds error conditions for `std::vector`.  The error occurs in the `permutation` function:

```
    if (index == spin_order.size()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pair<int, int> temp = block[state_order[0]][j];
            field[center.second - temp.second][center.first + temp.first] = -1; // <-- Out of bounds here
```

When I run this program, the values of the `std::pair<int, int>` variables `center` and `temp` are as follows:

```
center = {5,18}
temp = {0,0}
```

The value of `center.second - temp.second` well exceeds the highest row index, which is 9, thus you are accessing the `vector` out-of-bounds.  Anything after that line becomes a moot point since you are invoking undefined behavior.

Note that this was detected by changing the `field` declaration from using a raw array to `std::vector`.  Since Visual Studio checks boundary conditions for `std::vector` and `std::array` in debug mode, you should take advantage of this and declare all of your arrays either as `std::vector` or `std::array`, so that you can detect these errors easily, or at least verify you are not going out-of bounds.

In addition, both `vector` and `array` have an `at()` member function you can use to detect boundary conditions, and sprinkling `at()` calls instead of using `[ ]` to access your elements is also another way to debug your application, or at least verify you have no boundary access issues.

---

Now how to fix this?  You need to debug your code and see why `center` and/or `temp` is giving you values you didn't expect, or increase the size of your `field` vector/array to accommodate the index values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just confused indexing row-column condition. :(